# iframe video won't play on mobile phone when touched

Tags: video, iframe, mobile, video-streaming, pug

I imported a youtube video using `iframe, but it doesn't work on mobile, but runs perfectly on desktop.

By not working, I mean: the video doesn't start playing when it is touched and if it's double touched, the page zooms in.

code:

```
div#video
    iframe(src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/mfB19N3ZdS0' frameborder = '0', allowfullscreen = '')
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it doe snot work - what exactly is happening?

Comment: @Mick by not working, I mean: the video doesn't start to play when you touch it and if you double-touch it, the page zooms in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a `display: block` to `iframe` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Looking at webpage link you provided, the problem is that you have a DIV which is covering the video meaning that the play button can't be hit. It only happens when the browser is narrow, which is why you are only seeing it on mobile devices. It also seems to be safari specific which makes it harder to find.

If you take a look at the div with id "quotesRight" in either the an iOS inspector using developer tools and a connected iPhone, or in safari on a Mac with the browser reduced to a single column width, you will see that the div is on top of the video so you can't hit the play button:

[image]

If you delete this div in the browser inspector the video plays fine on the iOS device.

I'll leave the original answer in place below as it was definitely an issue when I looked first and it may help someone - it does not seem to give the SME content error now which makes sense as it clearly is not an SME video. Maybe this was just a false positive on their piracy checks.

Also the example HTML below is useful for checking as this definitely works across browsers (as far as I can see...).

**Original answer**

Assuming the HTML syntax is correct (I think your extract above is shorthand?) then I think the problem may be with the particular video you are using which appears to be restricted on certain devices by the content owner (SME in this case).

For example if you try to play it on Chrome on a Mac directly you get this message:

[image]

Using a simple example from W3schools, playing your video on an iPhone gives exactly the behaviour your describe.

Using a different example video (I tried one from the Google YouTube examples), plays fine.

Here is the sample code with the YouTube example video:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my code is a `jade code`. I'm using the code which `Google`gave me, after selecting `share`. `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mfB19N3ZdS0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: I think it is likely the same issue - replace the "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mfB19N3ZdS0" with "http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" and see what happens

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work. I also tried it with the `Google`example you posted and still not working :(
my `iframe` is enclosed in a bootstrap `col`, but this shouldn't create problems.

Comment: I tested the website on `iPhone 6s/5` and `Samsung S2`.

Comment: this is the website: www.fitnesscoachirina.com